Github Actions not recognizing jq with --arg
I have a workflow that looks like the following:
name: Site - Build and Deploy FTP

on:
  push:
    branches: main
    paths:
      - 'src/Site/Site/**'
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4.1.4
      
      - name: Setup .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
        with:
          dotnet-version: '6.0.x'
          include-prerelease: true
          
      - name: Install dependencies
        working-directory: src/Site/Site
        run: dotnet restore
        
      - name: Build with dotnet
        working-directory: src/Site/Site
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release
        
      - name: Publish
        working-directory: src/Site/Site
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp
        
      #substitute production appsettings entries to temp json file
      - name: App Settings Variable Substitution
        shell: bash
        run: | 
           cat ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp/appsettings.json | jq --arg my_secret ${{secrets.SQL_CONNECTION_STRING}} --arg email_secret ${{secrets.EMAIL_PASSWORD}} '.Config.SiteDb = $my_secret | .Config.EmailPassword = $email_secret' > newfile.json


It was working up until two weeks ago when it started failing on the substitute appsettings step.  The weird part is that I didn't change anything in the workflow. Also, I have a nearly identical workflow for another portion of the project which succeeds every time(the only difference in the .yml files is that it runs on a different project and subs out different settings from its own appsettings.json file.) Generally it will fails with a 127 error code, but the cat command will write the appsettings.json file to the console, so it is finding that file properly, so it must be the jq command it is having a problem with.
I tried removing the --arg options and substitution filters and replacing it with just "jq '.'" and that succeeds just fine. Then, I tried just doing "jq '.Config.SiteDb = 5 | .Config.EmailPassword = 9' and that succeeds. So it seems like something with --arg is messing up on this particular runner?

Use single quotes around ${{...}} and try again.

This works, thank you!!  I'm just confused now why it is not failing on other workflows that use ${{...}} without any quotes around it.

You're welcome! The secrets may contain symbols with special meaning for the shell that's why. They are not expanded when single quoted.

When you expand variables like this in a shell script in Github Actions, they are fully interpreted by the shell as if you had typed in those characters.
      #substitute production appsettings entries to temp json file
      - name: App Settings Variable Substitution
        shell: bash
        run: | 
           cat ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp/appsettings.json | jq --arg my_secret ${{secrets.SQL_CONNECTION_STRING}} --arg email_secret ${{secrets.EMAIL_PASSWORD}} '.Config.SiteDb = $my_secret | .Config.EmailPassword = $email_secret' > newfile.json

This means that any characters in the variable that might be interpreted by the shell will cause problems:

Spaces will cause there to be multiple arguments instead of one.
Quote characters may be treated by the shell as the start or end of a quoted block rather than themselves, and radically changing the interpretation of the rest of the line.
Backslashes may be treated as escape characters.
> and < may be treated as redirections.
| may be treated as pipeline steps.
...and many more.

Your example will behave differently depending on what characters happen to be in the password.
If you can guarantee that the string contains no single quotes, you can wrap single quotes around it.
A better alternative in most cases is to introduce environment variables. So, try something like this:
      #substitute production appsettings entries to temp json file
      - name: App Settings Variable Substitution
        shell: bash
        run: | 
           cat ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp/appsettings.json | jq --arg my_secret "$SQL_CONNECTION_STRING" --arg email_secret "$EMAIL_PASSWORD" '.Config.SiteDb = $my_secret | .Config.EmailPassword = $email_secret' > newfile.json
        env:
          SQL_CONNECTION_STRING: ${{secrets.SQL_CONNECTION_STRING}}
          EMAIL_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.EMAIL_PASSWORD}}

This time, the expansion "$SQL_CONNECTION_STRING" is done by the shell and not by GHA, so it won't reinterpret the contents of the string as shell characters. (The expansions in the env block are just producing plain strings that are not processed by the shell, they are just inserted in the environment variables as-is.)
One downside of this is that the environment variables are visible to every process started in the shell. If this is unacceptable, you could start your script by using bash's export -n VARIABLENAME to remove those variables from the environment while keeping them as shell variables.
